# Similar Functions - One works, the rest don't - Maybe a fresh set of eyes can see the problem? (Python CGI)

Tags: python, webforms, cgi

Working on a low intensity user registration script. In the error checking portion of the script (which effectively just checks to make sure the fields aren't left blank), the "addressError" function works without any problems at all.

But if I try to create errors in any other field, the script times out. Hopefully someone can see what it is that I'm missing?

**What Works:**

```
def check_address(user, formdata):
        if formdata.has_key("streetAddress") and formdata["streetAddress"].value != "":
                streetAddress = formdata["streetAddress"].value
                return streetAddress
        else:
                addressError(user, formdata)

def addressError(user, formdata):
        feedback = {"blank_address" : "Please enter a valid street address! We won't mail you anything you don't order. Promise."}
        stepTwoError(user, formdata, "blank_address", feedback)
```

**What Doesn't Work:**

```
def check_city(user, formdata):
        if formdata.has_key("city") and formdata["city"].value != "":
                city = formdata["city"].value
                return city
        else:
                cityError(user, formdata)

def cityError(user, formdata):
        feedback = {"blank_city" : "Please enter a city!"}
        stepTwoError(user, formdata, "blank_city", feedback)

def check_state(user, formdata):
        if formdata.has_key("state") and formdata["state"].value != "":
                state = formdata["state"].value
                return state
        else:
                stateError(user, formdata)

def stateError(user, formdata):
        feedback = {"blank_state" : "Please enter a state!"}
        stepTwoError(user, formdata, "blank_state", feedback)
```

EDIT: 
Code that Calls these methods:

```
def get_stepTwoData(user, formdata):
        firstName, lastName = check_name(user, formdata)
        streetAddress = check_address(user, formdata)
        city = check_city(user, formdata)
        state = check_state(user, formdata)
        zipCode = check_zipCode(user, formdata)

        return firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode
```

and in main:

```
  if regStep == "2":
                    firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode = get_stepTwoData(user, formdata)
                    make_step3(user, regStep, firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode, formdata)
```

As far as I'm concerned these three blocks are exactly the same, with "address", "state", and "city" used interchangeably. In fact, I could probably write a for function to cover all three of these at once. So why do two of them not work?

(Note: I'm not including the stepTwoError() function because I know that it works, since it works after being called by addressError - since that function doesn't change, i know *it* works. Therefore I can only assume the problem lies in the blocks posted.)

If I generate data with no errors, the script executes just fine, so I know there's no error in reading the data from the form. All the variables get returned on the next page with no issues.

This has been plaguing me for days. I just don't get it. I hope whatever the problem is will make me feel really stupid due to its simplicity.

Thanks!

EDIT: Okay, the error appears to be in my HTML. I haven't figured out exactly what in the script is causing the error, but in the html all forms are "input type='text' name='[name]'" except the address field, which is "input type = 'text'" - those extra spaces are messing something up, clearly.

Thanks to those who answered patiently, and yes, I did re-write the code to be more conside with less transcription error possibilities.

-tom

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that calls these methods?

Comment: Done. If no errors are generated, everything gets returned without issue.

Comment: I don't see any wrong. Are you sure the timeouts are not due to the next step (3) functions? Perhaps `make_step3(user, regStep,..)` should be `make_step3(user, 3,...)`?

Comment: If errors are generated, it never proceeds to step 3; stepTwoError rewrites the page, inserts the error feedback, and redirects the user there so they can fix the problem. And again, addressError works fine. I ran this line by line from a python interactive session and was able to come up with the right results for the other errors, but on the server it generates the 500 Internal Server Error. I see no reason for this. I'm glad I'm not the only one. Kind of. /grin

Comment: Also, make_step3 works fine (if no errors are generated, the script proceeds swimmingly), and the next page is also error free.

Comment: it is supposed that check_name also works...yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has mechanisms for creating functions dynamically that are useful in situations like this.  One is the metaclass, which requires some double-indirect thinking and can be tortuous to think thru. A simpler one (and a stepping stone to eventually learning metaclasses) is the closure, a function that creates a function by defining one locally and then returning that local function.  Here is how you can use a closure to generate all of your check_xxx functions:

```
def check_field(fieldname, errorname, errormessage):
    def fn(user, formdata):
        if fieldname in formdata and formdata[fieldname].value != '':
            return formdata[fieldname].value
        else:
            feedback = {errorname : errormessage}
            stepTwoError(user, formdata, errorname, feedback)
    return fn

check_address = check_field("streetAddress", "blank_address", "Please enter a valid street address!")
check_city = check_field("city", "blank_city", "Please enter a city!")
check_state = check_field("state", "blank_state", "Please enter a state!")
check_zip = check_field("zip", "blank_zip", "Please enter a zip code!")
```

Closures are great for eliminating copy-paste coding, and the frequent bugs where, after pasting a copy of an earlier function, one or more variable name references is left unchanged from the original.  Using a closure, you can be much more confident that your separate functions are really valid creations from the original template.

But I agree with @JohnMachin, I too suspect that your bug really is in the known-good-and-working method, `stepTwoError`. Try evaluating your input fields in a different order.  Does stepTwoError have a default argument that is a mutable object or list? Perhaps this is assumed to be empty, but retains values from a previous call?  Or does it update a global variable and leave it in a dirty state that leads to second-time-call errors?

Comment: Thanks for that detailed re-think of how I have it done. I'll definitely plug something like that in (this is the fourth revision or so, each time I've tried to consolidate the code more and more - it was atrocious at first), and this is the first time I've scripted something like this (clearly).

Comment: stepTwoError calls a few different other modules I've created for re-writing HTML pages and inserting errors. It only runs once per call of the main registry script, and then ports the user to a different page. Another reason I didn't want to post here is because I'd have to also post all the other modules too, which would be, I think, rude to do to everyone else, but I'll go over it all again. Again. If the errors are in those modules, I haven't found them yet, but I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

This "logic" is flawed: """(Note: I'm not including the stepTwoError() function because I know that it works, since it works after being called by addressError - since that function doesn't change, i know it works""

All you know is that it works when passed "blank_address" as the 3rd arg. Suppose it contains

```
if third_arg != "blank_address":
    while 1:
        pass
```